# JQuery DataTable sorting conflicts with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

So here it comes:
I used dataTable plugin to display my html table. When I clicked on the header of a column, that column got sorted. It works well. But when I tried to implement Ajax, it starts to have funky behavior. I am able to delete the DOM document via Ajax, and the row disappears from the table. But after that, if I clicked on the header of the table, suddenly, the row comes back and got displayed, even if it has already got deleted in the database! What's going on here with dataTable? I suspect that jQuery remove() doesn't remove the actual element from DOM of the page, somehow it remains there but not got displayed. So when I clicked on the header, the data table thought the row was still there. I got stuck. Can anyone help me with this? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I've never had trouble with jQuery remove() before. Does clicking the header actually fetch the data again? Or does it just sort the things you have in memory on the view. If it's the former, perhaps you have to tweak the configuration of the dataTable so that it accounts for the fact that you removed something when it reloads?

Comment: @jaydel Thanks for your help. I read the documentation on dataTable site, I think, dataTable got the data from DOM by default. That is why I got so confused. Because I saw it through firebugs that the tr element was deleted, how come <tr> element comes back again when I clicked the header of the column!!

Comment: That IS odd. I am kind of at the end of my knowledge. We use flexigrid for our tables (which has plenty of its own limitations and opacity) but it sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: @jaydel Well, I have been banging my head on the wall trying to resolve this annoying bug. But no luck. The dataTable site should provide a better documentation. Their documentation is too vague. But anyhow, i think I will try to build up the functions by myself then. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be one of many things happening here.

- Are you using a caching pipeline with "fnServerData"?
- I'm guessing when you delete the row from the datatable you are also making an ajax call to delete it from the database. Are you making sure the action completed before you try to sort again?
- Instead of doing a .remove() you could do a $("#tableID").fnDraw() on the success callback of your delete callback. This will cause datatables to grab the new data from the database and render the table for you.

When you use "bServerSide": true as an option for the datatable it is probably best practice to not remove the dom elements via jquery.remove() or another dom manipulation  approach but instead let datatable.fnDraw() handle adding and removing the columns based on the data it gets from the database for you.

Comment: Well, it has been a while. But thanks so much Keith. I mean I am using pure HTML datatable which doesn't involve server side processing. But you reminded me one thing that I should use dataTable's fnDeleteRow to delete the row instead of jQuery's remove(). Since I am using Ajax call, all I need is to pass the row number parameter along with the form data. And let the controller further pass params to the js call back, and from there I call the dataTable's fnDeleteRow with the row number that is passed to it. And it works like Charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I'm not sure the api was available at the time.  This question seems similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243394/deleted-datatable-row-gets-added-again-after-sorting?rq=1), but it's hard to tell without details.

Your problem may be removing the data from the DOM without removing it from the DataTable.  Their [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()) says to remove data this way:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'img.icon-delete', function () {
    table
        .row( $(this).parents('tr') )
        .remove()
        .draw();
} );
```

The DOM reflects the changes with the `.draw()` command and removes the row with datatable with the `.row().remove()` api call.