# Deleted DataTable row gets added again after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, datatable

I am using the [DataTables](https://datatables.net) jQuery plugin to display an HTML table and I have made an `AJAX` row deletion function that sends the deletion `POST` request in the background and displays the returned `HTML` message in an `#info` div and removes the related `HTML` row from the `DOM` using the jQuery `remove()` function.

Here's the function that gets called as `deleteData($id)` from the row's delete button:

```
function deleteData(id)
{
    var data = "id="+id;

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: data
        }
    ).done
    (
        function(data)
        {
            $('#info').html(data);

            var setID = id;

            $('#row' + setID).remove();         
        }
    );
}
```

Everything works good so far, the row gets deleted and the return message is shown, however, when I click a header to sort the rows again (ascendingly or descendingly) the deleted row reappears (in current session, not after a page reload) and it's still searchable, I wish to fix that.

From what I've read, the issue is that DataTables only loads the table once, but there's some way to make it load from the `DOM` at each sort. I have tried many different ways to do that but it doesn't work.

Comment: And what happens on the serverside, in `delete.php` ?

Comment: It simply gets the $id and deletes it from the database and echo "Row deleted" which gets displayed in the #info div.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I never used DataTable before but reading your question I was curious to learn a bit.

Then I noticed that you're removing the row merely using jQuery `.remove()` on the given row (in other words removing the real exposed DOM row), while [this DataTable page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.remove%28%29) states you should use the dedicated `.row().remove()`.

So in your example I guess you should replace `$('#row' + setID).remove();` by `yourDataTable.row($('#row' + setID)).remove();`.

EDIT.
Thanks to the @Bryan Ramsey's comment, I just realized that my suggested solution was incomplete:

- the statement used by the OP `$('#row' + setID).remove();` *only removes the row from DOM*, but keeps it in the DataTable object so it appears again furtherly
- then I suggested to rather use `yourDataTable.row($('#row' + setID)).remove();`, which really removes the row from the DataTable object, *but now keeps it in the DOM* so it doesn't visually disappear before the next change happens!
- so the real complete solution is `yourDataTable.row($('#row' + setID)).remove().draw();`, where `draw()` ensures the row to immediately disappear.

**NOTE: (if you're getting .row is not a function or $datatable is not defined) You must reintialize your datatable before removing the row as**

```
var $datatable = $('#datatable-selector').DataTable();
$datatable.row($deletingRowSelector).remove().draw();
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. I'd appreciate an upvote if you think the question is interesting.

Comment: anyone reading this where it still wont delete, be sure to add `.draw()` to the end of the string `yourDataTable.row($('#row' + setID)).remove().draw();` this tripped me up (its in the original linked docs though)

Comment: **Works perfectly** , search for many solution and finally found it here. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You need to delete it form the APi it self like this When the 'table' is called by:

```
var table = $('#yourDatatableId').DataTable();
```

Then:

```
...done
    (
        function(data)
        {
            //No need for these:
            //$('#info').html(data);    
            //var setID = id;

            table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).remove().draw();    
        }
    );
```

Comment: I had to use $('#row' + setID) instead of $(this).parents('tr') to get it to work, as instructed by the other answer..

Comment: You are removing the row manually. on the other hand, this works for my table. Why doesn't this work for you?